# Interpretation of Android Stack Trace

Tags: android, stack-trace

I received an error report with the following stack trace for an app I have in the Android Market:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service    com.k0gappsw.skibuddy.SBService@4051f4d0 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2473)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1127)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:150)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4385)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:849)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:607)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.k0gappsw.skibuddy.SBService.onStartCommand(SBService.java:316)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2456)
... 10 more
```

I have two questions:
1. Is the offending code at line 316 of SBService.java?
2. The code at that line is:
      Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
Any idea what could be going wrong with this? I have not seen the problem in my testing.

Comment: Have a look at [this question][1]. Seems to apply.

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963135/onstartcommand-after-service-process-is-killed-when-started-with-start-sticky

Comment: Thanks. I think that is my problem. Now I just need to figure out how I am going to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't you love mysterious stack traces that come in with random error reports!  I'll take a stab at answering your questions:

1. Yes, line 316 is the offending code.  The 'intent' must be null.
2. Maybe your service is being killed and recreated?  [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963135/onstartcommand-after-service-process-is-killed-when-started-with-start-sticky) might provide some insight into why the intent might be null.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It's my first app and first error report, and I wasn't sure how to proceed. I think the link is relevant and I need to look in that direction to understand the problem and devise a fix.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is the intent it is trying to grab is null hence the null pointer(obviously)

I would try this.

```
Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
```

I would also check if the activity that is calling this service is sending the intent correctly.